# Swapping rows to make a diagonally dominant matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Good day to everyone!
Need enlightening.

I tried to swap the rows of a matrix to make it diagonally dominant and here's what I made.

```
B = np.array([[7,1,2],[3,1,9],[0,5,1]])
Bcopy = B
C = np.array([0,2,1])
print(f'B: {B} \nBcopy: {Bcopy} \nC: {C}')
```

```
#Output
B: [[7 1 2],
    [3 1 9],
    [0 5 1]]
Bcopy: [[7 1 2],
        [3 1 9],
        [0 5 1]]
C: [0 2 1]
```

```
B[C,:] = Bcopy
print(f'B: {B} \n Bcopy: {Bcopy}')
```

```
#Expected output
B: [[7 1 2],
    [0 5 1],
    [3 1 9]]
Bcopy: [[7 1 2],
        [3 1 9],
        [0 5 1]]
C: [0 2 1]

#Actual output
B: [[7 1 2],
    [3 1 9],
    [3 1 9]]
Bcopy: [[7 1 2],
        [3 1 9],
        [3 1 9]]
C: [0 2 1]
```

Why ?

So, I made another one.

```
B = np.array([[7,1,2],[3,1,9],[0,5,1]])
Bcopy = B
C = np.array([0,2,1])
print(f'B: {B} \nBcopy: {Bcopy} \nC: {C}')
```

```
#Output
B: [[7 1 2],
    [3 1 9],
    [0 5 1]]
Bcopy: [[7 1 2],
        [3 1 9],
        [0 5 1]]
C: [0 2 1]
```

```
for i in range(3):
    B[C[i],:] = Bcopy[i,:]
    print(f'B: {B} \nBcopy: {Bcopy}')
    print(f'Bi: {B[C[i],:]} \t Bcopyi: {Bcopy[i,:]}')
print(f'C: {C}')
```

```
#Actual output
# 1st iteration
B: [[7 1 2],
    [3 1 9],
    [0 5 1]]
Bcopy: [[7 1 2],
        [3 1 9],
        [0 5 1]]
Bi: [7 1 2]    Bcopyi:[7 1 2]

# 2nd iteration
B: [[7 1 2],
    [3 1 9],
    [3 1 9]]
Bcopy: [[7 1 2],
        [3 1 9],
        [3 1 9]]
Bi: [3 1 9]    Bcopyi:[3 1 9]

# 3rd iteration
B: [[7 1 2],
    [3 1 9],
    [3 1 9]]
Bcopy: [[7 1 2],
        [3 1 9],
        [3 1 9]]
Bi: [3 1 9]    Bcopyi:[3 1 9]

C: [0 2 1]
```

I don't understand the sudden change in the 2nd iteration.
(I'm using Python 3.9.4 on a 64-bit computer.)

Looking forward for an explanation. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not making a copy of B with `Bcopy=B`.

Make a copy af your array as in the code below instead with *numpy.copy()*.

```
import numpy as np

B = np.array([[7,1,2],[3,1,9],[0,5,1]])
Bcopy = B.copy()
C = np.array([0,2,1])
print(f'B: {B} \nBcopy: {Bcopy} \nC: {C}')


B[C,:] = Bcopy
print(f'B: {B} \n Bcopy: {Bcopy}')
```

output :

```
B: [[7 1 2]
 [0 5 1]
 [3 1 9]]
 Bcopy: [[7 1 2]
 [3 1 9]
 [0 5 1]]
```

Comment: With numeric arrays, `Bcopy = B.copy()` is enough.  `Bcopy=B` isn't a copy of any sort, shallow or otherwise.

Comment: Thank you baptou. I actually didn't know about copy and deepcopy before u mentioned it. I tried your previous code and it worked. It was then that I knew that deepcopy is safer as cited here:

https://numpy.org/doc/1.20/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html?highlight=copy#numpy.copy